# When pronunciation does not follow etymology

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

*Autophagy* is defined as:

> Biology: Consumption of the body’s own tissue as a metabolic process occurring in starvation and certain diseases. [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/autophagy)

It also provides a pronunciation:

> /ɔːˈtɒfədʒi/

The Cambridge dictionary confirms this [pronunciation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/autophagy), as does [M-W Medical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/autophagy).

lexico.com lists the origin, as well:

> Mid 19th century from auto- + -phagy.

Essentially, the etymology is "self" + "eating."

The pronunciation seems to follow a syllabification of au / toph / a / gy , with an emphasis on a *non-sequitur* "toph." To this (American English) reader, a more sensible syllabification would be au / to / pha / gy.

Why don't the syllabification and pronunciation reflect the etymology?

Comment: If you were to follow that line of logic. Then there would be no American English.

Comment: I'm not aware of a -phagy word that does not follow this form.  It appears that the "ph" is almost always preceded by a vowel, and the vowel and the "ph" are combined into a syllable, separate from the "agy" syllable.

Comment: A word with a similar ending is "macrophage." I have heard it as mac / ro / phage, but never with the vowel and "ph" combined.

Comment: "-phage" and "-phagy" are pronounced differently.

Comment: More sensible to some. English reserves the right to continue with the word butchering begun by others.  How would you parse [lagniappe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagniappe)?

Comment: @rajah9 Similarly for _macrophagy_ vs _autophage_. This has nothing directly to do with etymology as such; it’s purely a matter of stress-based vowel variation in English. A stressed theme vowel (the ‘combining _-o-_’ used in Graeco-Latin compounds) is, as far as I can think, always pronounced /ɒ/, never /oʊ/. That syllabification is automatic in English, regardless of etymology (cf. also verbal _re/córd_ vs nominal _réc/ord_. Syllabification happens _synchronically_ in any given language; etymology is by definition _diachronic_; they are very separate things.

Comment: @user888379 Probably more to do with the fact that _automaton_ was borrowed directly from Greek, whereas _automobile_ is French (coined from a mix of Greek and Latin elements). In general, stress retention is more common in recognisably Classical borrowings than in ones that come through French or German, where adaption to inherited English stress patterns (with a preference for initial stress) is more frequent. But frequency of usage also plays a part sometimes – hard to say.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise that orthography prescribes pronunciation.

Comment: I spoke of etymology leading syllabification and pronunciation, not orthography, @marcellothearcane.

Comment: @Brad - There would be no English at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Isn’t *Indo-European* said with close /o/ not open /ɔ/ in its second syllable, or doesn’t that one really count? For me it doesn’t reduce there, behaving as though it were still some unassimilated *“double⸗barrelled”* compound word whose separate components retained their own original stress and unreduced vowels. All the *Indo-* compound words are like that for me.

Comment: @tchrist The reduction is optional there for me, but that’s an _unstressed_ theme vowel. Unstressed theme vowels are mostly /ə/, but sometimes /oʊ/, but stressed ones are never either (at least I haven’t been able to think of an example that is). The distribution appears to be complementary: stressed always /ɒ/; unstressed always /ə/ or /oʊ/.

Answer (score 5):

#### This is not unique to the pronunciation of *autophagy*

There is no principle saying that the pronunciation of a word must always divide it into parts that correspond to its etymological components. That's just the way compounds formed in English from English words (like *[paperhanger](https://www.onelook.com/?w=paperhanger)*) tend to be pronounced. But not all compounds are formed in English from English words.

The pronunciation /ɔːˈtɒfədʒi/ for *autophagy* follows a very common pronunciation pattern for Greek-derived compound words ending in *-y.* I describe it in my answer to the similar previous question *[Pronunciation of tetrameter, pentameter, etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/382048).* There are scores of other words pronounced like this, including *biology* (and *-ology* words in general).*

#### Sometimes multiple stress patterns are possible for a word like this

For certain words of this type, it seems to be somewhat common for some speakers to use the stress pattern of English compound words instead. For example, the John Wells quotation in my linked answer talks about "cardiologists, cardiac surgeons, paramedics and nurses" using the pronunciation /ˌθrɒmbəʊˈlaɪsɪs/ for *thrombolysis.* My high school chemistry teacher used the pronunciation /haɪdroʊˈlaɪsɪs/ for *hydrolysis*: she was aware of the pronunciation with stress on the second syllable, but consciously chose to pronounce it with stress on the first and third syllable in the classroom to emphasize the etymology/structure of the word in her lectures.

The pronunciations of rare scientific terms are often not as fixed as the pronunciations of other, more common words. Many scientists don't care that much about pronouncing things according to a system, and the ones that do care about it don't all agree about what the system should be. I wouldn't expect anyone to start pronouncing *biology* as /baɪoʊ.loʊdʒi/ or *astronomy* as /æstroʊ.noʊmi/, but it seems more plausible that some scientists might use a pronunciation like /ˈɔːtoʊˌfeɪdʒi/. You'd have to listen to find out; I found what seems to be one example through Youglish: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AA7akJ21ZI&feature=youtu.be&t=493

#### *Side note on syllabification

The syllabification of words like this is actually a bit of a controversial issue in linguistics. Some linguists would say that /ɔːˈtɒfədʒi/ and /baɪˈɒlədʒi/ are divided into the syllables /ɔːˈtɒ.fə.dʒi/ and /baɪˈɒ.lə.dʒi/. It's clear that English words tend not to end in vowels like /ɒ/, but it's a little less obvious that this restriction applies to stressed word-internal syllables.

If we consider the stressed syllable to be /ˈtɒf/ rather than /ˈtɒ/, the explanation would be either that stressed syllables in English tend to "capture" adjacent consonants, or that stressed "short vowels" in particular tend to "capture" a following consonant.

Comment: Forcing each component to retain its original, uncombined stress (and hence also reduction) makes everything sound like some sort of hyphenated word, so like *extra-ordinary* /ˈɛkst͡ʃrə ˈordəˌneri/ ɴᴏᴛ  /ɪksˈt͡ʃrɔrdəˌneri/;
*photo-graphy* /ˈfoto ˈgræfi/ ɴᴏᴛ  /fəˈtɔgrəfi/;
*homo-genous* /ˈhomo ˈd͡ʒinəs/ ɴᴏᴛ /həˈmɔd͡ʒənəs/;
*andro-geny* /ˈænd͡ʒro ˈd͡ʒini/ ɴᴏᴛ /ænˈd͡ʒrɔd͡ʒəni/;
*iso-sceles* /ˈaɪso ˈsiliz/ ɴᴏᴛ /aɪˈsɔsəˌliz/. These sound like they mean something else, like if *androgenies* meant only **boy** djinni not girl ones. :)

Comment: As your answer (and linked answer) state: syllabification and pronunciation are controversial issues in linguistics. Your examples show how that promiscuous short vowel can capture a following consonant. And @tchrist, your examples gave me a wonderful insight into how often this phenomenon occurs.

Comment: @rajah9 Related to your *autophagy* case are an even more ungainly (read:
*cacophonous*) pair of examples in two words describing fish-eating
creatures or diets: *ichthyo-phagous* would be /ˈɪkθio ˈfæɡəs/ not
/ɪkθiˈɔfəɡəs/, and *pisci-vorous* would be /ˈpɪsi ˈvorəs/ not /pɪˈsɪvərəs/.
To a native speaker, the “bogus” pronunciations have deeply nasty
mishearings. Similarly you would no more dare risk *autophagous* ever being heard as
/ˈɔto ˈfægəs/ not /ɔˈtɔfəgəs/ than *cacophonus* ever being head as /ˈk[e∼æ∼ɑ]ko
ˈfonʌs/ instead of /kəˈkɔfənəs/. :)

Comment: an**ti**thesis, om**ni**potent, hy**per**bole, su**per**fluous...